# How to define tensors similar to Riemann tensor in xAct xTensor xTras

Tags: function-construction, tensors, xact, field-theory

I'm working on a project where we deal with objects very similar to Riemann tensor. In fact they are Christoffel symbols for higher spins. I'm using **xTras** for modeling problems in wolfram mathematica. I'm struggling to define Christoffel symbols that could **hold their form** and do not expand during simplification processes.

Here is my code which I'm using

[image]

I've defined 3rd order and 4th order Christoffel symbols like this.

[image]

As you can see they fulfill the following equation

[image]

which is equivalent to:

[image]

Here `A` vectors are for symmetrization purposes.

[image]

When doing computations with this tensors after simplification they expand by underlying tensor `H` and it is a big pain to combine them back into their original form.

E.g: Adding two Gammas must give Gamma without printing the expansion. I know that Riemann tensors defined in xTras behave exactly like that, they do not expand the underlying metric structure, instead they hold their form.

**How can I define my Cristofel symbols like that?**

[image]